# Load state of a module in /proc/modules

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, procfs

From the answer to this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152507/module-marked-f-in-proc-modules), it is given that the fifth field of `/proc/modules` is the load state of the module and can be either `Live` or `Loading` or `Unloading`. However in my `Ubuntu 14.04` system and some other systems, I could find only the value `Live` for this field. Is it true that the field can have other values too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 3 possible states for this field:

- `Live`
- `Loading`
- `Unloading`

You can see this in kernel sources, in [kernel/module.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/module.c#L3724) file:

```c
/* Informative for users. */
seq_printf(m, " %s",
           mod->state == MODULE_STATE_GOING ? "Unloading" :
           mod->state == MODULE_STATE_COMING ? "Loading" :
           "Live");
```

The description of `mod->state` can be found in `enum module_state`, in [include/linux/module.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/module.h#L206):

```c
enum module_state {
    MODULE_STATE_LIVE,      /* Normal state. */
    MODULE_STATE_COMING,    /* Full formed, running module_init. */
    MODULE_STATE_GOING,     /* Going away. */
    MODULE_STATE_UNFORMED,  /* Still setting it up. */
};
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible for the field to have other values, but these are transitional states and you would have a hard time spotting them from outside the kernel. The `Loading` state for example only persists from the time the module has been fully loaded into memory until its initialization is complete. Typically, this would take only microseconds.